# Convert fixed length text file into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to convert a fixed length text file into a MySQL Table.
My biggest problem is that multiple cells are contained on each line, and this is how the file is sent to me, and the main reason why I want to convert it.

The cells are all of a specific length; however all are included on the one line.

For example the first 3 positions (1 - 3) of a line are the IRT, the next three positions (4 - 6) are the IFTC the next 5 positions (7 - 11) are the FSC, etc.

As the file can contain up to 300 lines of records, I need an easy way to import it straight into the SQL Tables.

I have been searching the net for hours trying to find a solution, however without comma separation I haven't been able to find a working solution yet.

I would like to code this solution in `PHP`, if possible as well. And am willing to do the long yards of working out how to use the function required to do this if someone could give me the function name, I don't expect people to write my code out for me.

Comment: Well you could split by `\n` or `\r\n` to get your "rows"

Then you could use substr() to get the parts of each row you want

and then insert

Comment: Use **LOAD DATA INFILE**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: @ypercube: The [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) description you refer to does not handle fixed-length fields with no delimiters separating the fields.

Comment: @Jonathan: I was under the  impression it could handle fixed-length fields. Maybe older versions couldn't ?

Comment: @Jonathan: The first user comment! (which tells us something about the documentation...)

Comment: And a few previous obscure lines. Adding them in my answer.

Comment: @ypercube: I confess - I did not even scan, much less read, the user comments.  You're right, the information is there (dated 2005!).  And one reason for it not being documented formally may be exactly the issues I mentioned - your table definition has to exactly match the fixed format file definition.

Answer (score 7):

File:

```
testfile.txt (4 rows)

AAA11111xx
BBB22222yy
CCC33333zz
DDD 444 aa
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestLoadDataInfile
( a VARCHAR(3)
, b INT(5)
, c CHAR(2)
) CHARSET = latin1;
```

Code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\...\\testfile.txt'
INTO TABLE TestLoadDataInfile
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

Result:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TestLoadDataInfile ;
+-----+-------+----+
| a   | b     | c  | 
+-----+-------+----+ 
| AAA | 11111 | xx | 
| BBB | 22222 | yy | 
| CCC | 33333 | zz | 
| DDD |   444 | aa | 
+-----+-------+----+
```

The LOAD DATA INFILE documentation is not very good at this point (fixed-size fields). Here's the related parts:

> - If the FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS
>     ENCLOSED BY values are both empty
>     (''), a fixed-row (nondelimited)
>     format is used. With fixed-row format,
>     no delimiters are used between fields
>     (but you can still have a line
>     terminator). Instead, column values
>     are read and written using a field
>     width wide enough to hold all values
>     in the field. For TINYINT, SMALLINT,
>     MEDIUMINT, INT, and BIGINT, the field
>     widths are 4, 6, 8, 11, and 20,
>     respectively, no matter what the
>     declared display width is.
>
> LINES TERMINATED BY is still used to
>   separate lines. If a line does not
>   contain all fields, the rest of the
>   columns are set to their default
>   values. If you do not have a line
>   terminator, you should set this to ''.
>   In this case, the text file must
>   contain all fields for each row.
>
> Fixed-row format also affects handling
>   of NULL values, as described later.
>   Note **that fixed-size format does not
>   work if you are using a multi-byte
>   character set**.
>
> ---
>
> NULL handling
>
> With fixed-row format (which is used
>   when FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS
>   ENCLOSED BY are both empty), NULL is
>   written as an empty string. Note that
>   this causes both NULL values and empty
>   strings in the table to be
>   indistinguishable when written to the
>   file because both are written as empty
>   strings. If you need to be able to
>   tell the two apart when reading the
>   file back in, you should not use
>   fixed-row format.
>
> ---
>
> Some cases are not supported by LOAD
>   DATA INFILE:
>
> - Fixed-size rows (FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS ENCLOSED BY
>     both empty) and BLOB or TEXT columns.
>
> ---
>
> - User variables cannot be used when
>     loading data with fixed-row format
>     because user variables do not have a
>     display width.

Comment: Oh, interesting!  Am I reading this correctly if I interpret it as: if you have a table with a simple `b INT` column (as opposed to `b INT(5)`, you won't be able load the data with 5 characters for the INT data?  And even if the column can take up to 9 digits (so the table is created with `b INT(9)`, you won't be able to load a file that happens to have just 5 characters reserved for the column?  So, you can't read arbitrary fixed data into the DBMS; just stuff that happens to be formatted with exactly the right widths for the specific table.

Comment: @Jonathan: I just tested it and yes, you are right. You can however read data into CHAR or VARCHAR fields and then CAST them into the wanted datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't like it very much, but there really isn't an easy way to do what you're after.  A long time ago (circa 1991), I wrote a tool, DBLDFMT (for 'database load format') to deal with such fixed-length, non-delimited files.  It is tuned to generating the load format preferred by Informix databases (so it uses a pipe symbol by default to separate the fields, but of course you can tune that with a command line option or an environment variable).  It can, however, create delimited data which you can then process more normally, probably using the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command.

Contact me by email (see my profile) if you want the source code for DBLDFMT.  (The current version, 3.17 from 2008, does not have direct support for CSV output.  It would not be hard to add it.  You can, more or less, achieve the required effect, but it should be a lot easier than it is.)